# The Color Purple

Tags: syntax

Is 'the color purple' a syntactically sound sentence? Or would 'the purple color' be a more standard version. I'm basing this on the fact that adjective-noun order seems a more acceptable syntax.

Comment: It is not a *sentence* because a sentence has at least a subject and a verb.  I think you mean is it a syntactically sound *phrase*.

Comment: The idea that a sentence is “a group of words expressing a complete thought” has been widely discredited—even though it contains a good deal of truth. But it is true that many single words can be sentences, as C.T. Onions observed: “Many single words or self-contained groups of words, of any size, may perform the work of a sentence. "Yes" and "no" are long-established sentence-words; they are equivalent to sentences. The grammarian James Sledd wrote aptly that “no useful definition can be framed to include all and only the things [that] are often called sentences.”

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Color_Purple

Comment: @MvLog I agree with your point. But barring more context, in which *the color purple* could be considered an elliptical sentence along the lines of *yes (that's what I think)*, it can't really be considered a sentence. We don't have any basis for it to be meaningful on its own. (Aside from its meaning as a book and movie title, which is different.)

Comment: @MvLog - OK, then; "the color purple" is not a *full-formed* sentence.  Yes, a lot of things people say as "sentences" are not necessarily subject-verb sentences, but if therefore you say "A sentence can be anything at all", I don't think that's useful for a learner, because it doesn't give us any way to distinguish between, say, "Train running" (which could certainly be something somebody says) and "The train is running" (which is a classically well-formed sentence).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to say. Both are perfectly acceptable.

Saying "the color purple" you refer to purple which in this case is a noun. Purple is a color.

On the other hand, "the purple color", you're referring to the color which is purple and in this case purple plays the role of the adjective.

Comment: To add an example: "My favorite color is the color purple.  That's why I like the purple color of this painting."